# Pandas: Check Column Membership in Other Column (Same Row)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
       A        B
0   [C, D, E]   C
1   [X, Y, Z]   G
```

created from:

```
example = pd.DataFrame({"A":[["C", "D", "E"], ["X", "Y", "Z"]], "B":["C", "G"]})
```

I want to count how often a value occurs both in the list in column `A` and under column `B`.

So the correct output for value `C` would be 1 and for value `Z` would be 0.  Any suggestions without resorting to going row-by-row (and losing out on vectorization)?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AshishAcharya I can do this using `iterrows` but the goal is to take advantage of vectorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily a vectorized approach, but using **`apply`**:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['B'] in x['A'], axis=1).astype(int)

0    1
1    0
dtype: int32
```

*Edit: Not even including **`np.in1d`** anymore because of how badly it scaled*

Surprisingly, I got a huge performance boost using a basic list comprehension over **`apply`**:

```
pd.Series([b in a for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]).astype(int)
```

Some timings:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*5000)

In [158]: %timeit pd.Series([b in a for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]).astype(int)
1.55 ms ± 40.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [159]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: x['B'] in x['A'], axis=1).astype(int)
344 ms ± 1.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that simply explodes the list and counts using `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[["C", "D", "E"], ["X", "Y", "Z"]], "B":["C", "G"]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame([j, df.loc[i]['B']] for i in df.index for j in df.loc[i]['A'])

df1['same'] = (df1[0] == df1[1]).astype(int)

df1.groupby(0).same.sum()
```

Output:

```
0
C    1
D    0
E    0
X    0
Y    0
Z    0
Name: same, dtype: int64
```